# If I am embedding an SVG using an <object> tag, is it possible to use normal DOM methods in JS to access the children elements?

Tags: javascript, svg

If I am embedding an SVG using an `<object>` tag, is it possible to use normal DOM methods to access the children elements?

**Example**

First a simple SVG:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0,0 100, 100">
  <defs>
    <style>
      #cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 4;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <title>Circles</title>
  <g id="cls-1">
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="10" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Then an HTML file that embeds the SVG using  and tries to access the group defined in the SVG within a script:

```
<html>

<body>
    <object
      type="image/svg+xml"
      height="200px"
      data="mysvg.svg"
    ></object>
    <button onclick="myAnimate()" />

    <script>
      const myAnimate = () => {
        const group = document.getElementById("cls-1");
      };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Wy doesn't this work?

I see in the devtools that the first child of this  is #document. So it seems to have it's own DOM, I think I read this, but still have not wrapped my head around how it works.

Is there a way to access the element with id "cls-1" from JS?

EDIT: one way to make this work is to add the script within the svg itself; the DOM methods work normally for the DOM in the SVG

Comment: woops, that was supposed to be document in the example

Comment: Are you using a web server here or just a filesystem. If the latter there's probably no way to make this work. If the former, the deleted answer is the way to go.

Comment: Never mind, I see the issue too.

Comment: I am using the file system for now. The deleted answer did not work for me.

Comment: Is it really the case that to be able to manipulate the SVG I must necessarily use inline SVG? @RobertLongson

Comment: Not at all, but if you want to use more than one file, you can't use the file system. That's why the deleted answer didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use *contentDocument*

Example:

```
<script>
  const myAnimate = () => {
    const group = document.querySelector('object')
        .contentDocument.getElementById("cls-1");
  };
</script>
```